# How to I plot a color vector? Is there a different method I could try?

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors, an x vector, a y vector, and a color vector, each with 50 elements. My goal is to have the color change every 10 elements.

my code example:

```
x = (50:-1:1);
y = (50:-1:1);
color = 'bbbbbbbbbbmmmmmmmmmmccccccccccggggggggggrrrrrrrrrr';
plot(x,y,color)
```

I also have tried using a for-loop with a color vector but when i said color(i) it would not work. Any ideas/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: It is relatively simple if you want to use markers with no line. But it seems you want to draw lines. In this case, consider the fact that between n dots you have n-1 lines. You can still use a for loop with plot function, plotting 10 or 11 dots each time, depending if you want the color to change every 10 points or every 10 lines

Answer (score 0):

Although it can be made in more elegant way, I think in this simple case there's no reason to complicate it. Following code will do what you described:

```
x = (50:-1:1);
y = (50:-1:1);
color = ["black","magenta","cyan","green","red"];
for i=1:(size(x,2)-9)
    plot(x(i:(i+9)),y(i:(i+9)),color(ceil(i/10)));
    hold on;
end
```

Instead of defining `color`, your way, I make it vector of strings. Plots are generated in loop, and overlap each other, so it is not the best solution in the matter of memory management, but let you avoid gaps between the parts of graph.